# Is there a mount unionfs like system to manage permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, file-permissions, cloud

I have a cloud account with a folder on it. I mount it correctly locally using rclone on Ubuntu. Fine.

But all the files are owned by me, all with the same rights (let's say 0664). I would like to specify file specific access rights (ex: executable for some files, read-only for some other).

Is there a "layered" filesystem that I could mount on top of my folder, who would manage the rights by storing them in a text file? There are tools that put a layer on top of a mount: encfs, unionfs...

Any idea?

Notes: I known that those files would still be accessible otherwise. It is really only to manage their access rights locally only. The files will be encrypted anyway...

Comment: For everyone who sees this question: doing this is a monumentally bad idea. It's like putting all your passwords in an Excel sheet on Google Drive. It's a very bad security practice. `ssh` actually tries to protect you from this and this question is essentially about circumventing that protection. Unless you really know what you're doing, don't try to be smarter than the devs and just use the system in the way they intended it.

Comment: I think the idea of this type of network mount, is that each user has their own mount. Therefore it is OK to show just your permissions. It does however make it impossible to give permissions to others via the mount.

Comment: `overlayfs`. But I won't be providing a complete answer because as mtak said, your private keys shouldn't leave your computer. `ssh` tries to make sure `id_rsa` is only readable for you, but it's also readable for everyone at Google. Hopefully it's at least password-protected.